# SQL Server - NT AUTORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGIN error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My supervisor added permission to my account so that I can update a view, but after my account was changed with the permission, I am now getting the NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGIN error whenever I try to run and view the views.

When I looked around, the views are now showing some kind of an error mark on the view. And the encrypted in the properties options shows "True."

[image]

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba. But why did you not ask your supervisor or your DBA for assistance first? And provide context - you are encountering this error how / when?

Comment: @sMor - I already did, but I've been instructed to research this issue on my own and see what I can find. I've looked around, but haven't found solid.